# react-hook-form reset errors and clear schema validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Using `react-hook-form` and `vest`

I have the following setup (It's **SIMPLIFIED** but same idea in my app)  : [Application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j9wnfz?file=src%2FApp.js)

A vest resolver :

```
import { create, enforce, test, skipWhen } from 'vest';

let previousCode;

export const formValidator = create('formValidator', (formValue) => {
  // console.log('formValue => ', formValue);
  // code
  test('code', 'Code is a required field', () => {
    enforce(formValue.code).isNotEmpty();
  });
  test('code', 'Code must have 4 characters', () => {
    enforce(formValue.code).lengthEquals(4);
  });

  skipWhen(!formValue.showOptional, () => {
    test('optionalCode', 'Code must have 4 characters', () => {
      enforce(formValue.optionalCode).lengthEquals(4);
    });
  });
});
```

And 3 fields

```
  const formFunctions = useForm({
    resolver: vestResolver(formValidator),
    defaultValues: {
      code: '',
      showOptional: false,
      optionalCode: '',
    },
  });
```

one that is always show, and a second optional that is shown only if user check the checkbox.

Now the issue is with the validation and error. When I trigger the checkbox and new fields are added or hidden, I would like the errors to disappear and the validation to be cleared.

Technically I should just need to do

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    clearErrors();
  }, [showOptionalCode]);
```

This would hide the error, but the field previously shown is still validated in vest so I also need to do

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    clearErrors();
    //formValidator.reset();
  }, [showOptionalCode]);
```

even if I `unregister` the input I am still required to reset the `formValidator`

The issue with this is when a NestedComponent clear the errors, I need to pass a reference to the validator which because it is not retrievable when we use `useFormContext` which is kind of a problem.

So I think this should not be needed and there must be wrong with my setup.

Comment: Are you accessing the errors and warnings through `vest` or through `react-hook-form`?  Without being able to see how you have everything wired up, it's hard to know for certain, but you should make sure that you're using `react-hook-form` as your source of truth and allowing it to rely on `vest` rather than relying on both yourself.  If that is the issue, it's likely caused by an optimization in `react-hook-form` that wraps the form state in a proxy

Comment: Fundamentally Vest is stateful. This kind of runs against what `react-hook-form` wants to do which is have its own internal state for errors. Personally I think the solution here would be to modify `vestResolver` such that it always resets `formValidator` every time. You can't use vest's stateful incremental validation thing with `react-hook-form` as it just passes the entire new set of values each time anyway.